# Accessing & Manipulating DOM for JS Module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I'm new to importing modules in ES6. I have a simple module with a function for creating and appending an HTML element.

I am able to call and pass arguments to the function, however, I cannot read any properties from the DOM. I am receiving errors such as this:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentNode')`

I have simplified my code below:

**main.js**

```
import * as watm_fn from "./modules/functions.js";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
  watm_fn.createToggle("#container");
}
```

**functions.js**

```
export function createToggle(elm) {

  const toggleElementID = document.getElementById(elm);
  const languageToggle = document.createElement("select");

  toggleElementID.parentNode.replaceChild(languageToggle, toggleElementID);

}
```

I get a similar error when trying to return the innerHTML of `toggleElementID`

Is accessing and manipulating the DOM via an imported module possible? And if so, what am I doing wrong?

*(I am not using node or jquery in this project)*

Answer (score 1):

Well I feel dumb. I'm used to coding in jQuery where you include the "#" in front of your IDs, but I forgot that `getElementById` does not require that. Removing that from my passed argument resolved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentNode')
```

This error suggests that the below line is failing `toggleElementID` is `null`:
toggleElementID.parentNode.replaceChild(languageToggle, elm);

### Why is toggleElementID null ?

Look at the code searching for the element

```
const toggleElementID = document.getElementById(elm);
```

As per [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
An Element object describing the DOM element object matching the specified ID, *or null if no matching element was found in the document.*

So there is no matching element found with the supplied `elm` id.

Comment: The code creating it is `const toggleElementID = document.getElementById(elm);`

I still get an error if I remove the `createElement` line and just try to access the innerHTML, as stated in my original post.

Comment: The error is suggesting that `toggleElementID` is `null`, *so you can't access `.parentNode` on it*, not that `toggleElementID.parentNode` would be `null`. Also you mixed up `toggleElementID` with `languageToggle`: no one expects the latter to have a parent. `languageToggle` is `null` because `document.getElementById` didn't find the element with the ID `elm`, which can be because of several reasons (typo, not-yet-loaded document / element etc.)

Comment: That's right, I got a bit swayed. Will update the answer accordingly.